# Storing long static array in Angular

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular application, where should I keep a list of countries (long static array) and how to reference it from contoller? I don't want to store it in controller.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just create `constant service` and put all your `countries list` in that provider.
And just `inject` that service into your `controller` where you need that values.

```
app.constant("country", [       
                            {"code": "AFG","name":"Afghanistan"},
                            {"code":"ALB","name":"Albania"},
                            {"code":"DZA", "name":"Algeria"},
                            {"code":"ASM", "name":"American Samoa"},
                               ..........]); //countries List
```

Inject this service into controller.

```
app.controller("demoCtrl",['$scope','country',function($scope,country){
      //countries automatically imported into controller

}]);
```

[Angular Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Comment: I've put  .constant into my services.js and .controller into my controllers.js  (.controller('MyProfileCtrl', ["countries", function (countries, $scope,.... ) and console says "$scope is undefined"

Comment: write controller as .controller('MyProfileCtrl', ["$scope","countries", function ($scope,countries,.... )

Comment: Works. Could you please point me to the Angular docs where this is described? I needed to put all the arguments in the quotes and duplicate them the same way as "$scope". Btw. now I want to put "app.constant" into separate file- it means creating new module, right?

Comment: no need to create new module. here replace app name with you module name

Comment: I've put countries (angular.constant("countries",...) into /js/constants/countries.js Console says "Unknown provider: countriesProvider <- countries". I'm missing some config. It works fine when I put ".constant" along my services in services.js (angular.module('starter.services',..)

Comment: Dont use angular.constant because its service. so your moduleName.constant is better approach

Comment: so I add countries to my current "services module" or create new one in order to have it in sepparate file, is that ok?

Comment: Is it possible to get name value 'Algeria' by using its code 'DZA' in the controller?

Comment: For that you need the change the json format.@Selva